Using avif overlays
Section 2.3 of avif spec says that it supports multi-layered images or overlays.
Is this featured supported on GIMP or Inkscape or even a commandline tool like imagemagick?
E.g usage: how can I list all layers within an avif file? How do I merge separate images 1.avif, 2.avif, ... into layer1 layer2, ... of out.avif

Inkscape doesn't support AVIF, only the import of some raster image formats.  Inkscape is a vector image editor and can't directly edit raster images at all.  GIMP has support for layers in its own XCF format. Although it supports opening and exporting AVIF files, I've no idea if it supports all the features of that format.  I can't really find anything online which says it supports layers in AVIF. Sorry about that.
